# Watchpoint not triggered when inserting to ArrayList

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea

I have a java program, it has a global variable `ArrayList<Integer> al` I put a watchpoint on it to track changes to this variable. I found that watchpoint only gets triggered when there is assignment to the this varible, like this `al = new ArrayList<>`, but when I insert into this list, the watchpoint is not getting triggered. I guess this is a normal behaviour. So is there any setting we can do, so that we get trigger everytime we insert or remove from the list.

The actual code for reference

```
public MyClass {

private static ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList(); Put a watchpoint here

public static void main(String args[]){
    al = new ArrayList<>(); // watchpoint gets triggered here
    Integer a = 1;
    al.add(a); // watchpoint not getting triggered here
  }
}
```

EDIT

My actual scenario is this list can be modified from other threads, so I thought putting a watchpoint over it will be a good idea to know which thread modified it and also look into its stack trace

Comment: Can you provide your java code?

Comment: @ZufarSunagatov added my code

Comment: 1) Are you running in debug mode? 2) Do other breakpoints work correctly? 3) If you put a breakpoint a little bit before this code is hit, does that trigger? Can you then step forwards to this code?

Comment: @Jorn yes running in debug mode, yes other bp works as expected.
Didnt understand your 3rd question

Comment: Once you hit a breakpoint, your debugger will have a "step forwards" button. You can use that to reach the place in the code where you claim the breakpoint isn't hit. Doing that will probably tell you *why* it isn't hit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So is there any setting we can do, so that we get trigger everytime we insert or remove from the list.

Well, if you add or remove elements from an `ArrayList`, the watchpoint will not be triggered, because `ArrayList` object itself is not changing.

I have an idea that you can monitor changes to the elements inside the ArrayList, you would need to implement your own custom `class ArrayList`. This way you can set callback functions that get triggered whenever an element is added or removed from the list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class CustomObservableArrayList<T> extends ArrayList<T> {

    private Consumer<T> addCallback;
    private Consumer<T> removeCallback;

    public CustomObservableArrayList(Consumer<T> addCallback, Consumer<T> removeCallback) {
        super();
        this.addCallback = addCallback;
        this.removeCallback = removeCallback;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T element) {
        boolean result = super.add(element);
        if (result && addCallback != null) {
            addCallback.accept(element);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(Object element) {
        boolean result = super.remove(element);
        if (result && removeCallback != null) {
            removeCallback.accept((T) element);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```